# In C, copying of array like this is not possible. Why? and best hack

Tags: c, data-structures

```
int x[10],y[10];
x = y;
```

I am thinking of a simple hack, which would enable me to get this effect.

Comment: I know you have tagged it C but still confirming...would C++ solution be OK?

Comment: err, why a hack?  Why not just understanding how to program in the language?

Comment: caf answered your question about the best way to copy data.  For why a simple assignment is not possible, maybe you will find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035066/type-of-an-array/2035255#2035255 useful (it's my answer to a similar question).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can wrap them in `struct`s to use simple assignment:

```
struct foo { int a[10]; } x, y;
x = y;
```

But really, just use `memcpy`.

Comment: GCC actually emits a call to `memcpy` with that example.

Answer (score 11):

You need to use `memcpy` (or `memmove`) to transfer a block of memory.

```
memcpy(x, y, sizeof(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use memcpy(), or copy it yourself with a for(i=0;i<10;i++) loop