# Understanding arrays in Objective-C / C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, variable-assignment

I just made my first steps moving into [Objective-C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C). I have a very simple question about how arrays works.

I have two .m files:

1)

```
Line = origin[6];
forloop(i...i++) {
    origin[i]=7;
}
[buildSubview:origin];
```

2)

```
Line response[6]; 

-(id)buildSubview:(Line[])origin {
    *response=*origin;
    NSLog(@"response[1]=%o",response[1]);
    NSLog(@"origin[1]=%o",origin[1]);
    ........
    .....
}
```

The output I get is:

```
response[1]=0; <-- I would expect the same value as origin
origin[1]=7;
```

But if I ask to print the value at index 0 I get what I expected:

```
response[0]=7; <-- Now they are the same
origin[0]=7;
```

I am asking why two different values ? And also, why if I write

```
response=origin;
```

I get an incompatible assignment compile error?

Comment: What is `forloop` instruction?

Comment: is just a shorthand, what I meant was for(int i=0;i<6;i++){...}

Comment: Why don't you show us real code?

Comment: sorry, I tought the core of the question was clear enough without the real code. Next time I will add the full listing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Briefly, [sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035066/type-of-an-array/2035255#2035255), the name of an array in C "decays" to a pointer to the first element of the array, and that is causing you trouble.

When you write

```
response=origin;
```

The name `origin` on the RHS "decays" to be of type `Line *`, and points to the first element of `origin` array, whereas `response` is of type "array [6] of Line".  Since the two types are not compatible (it doesn't make sense to initialize an array with a pointer), it is an error.

Now,

```
*response=*origin;
```

doesn't copy all the memory in `origin` to `response`.  As I mentioned above, and in more detail in the link above, `origin` points to the first element of the `origin` array in this context, so `*origin` is actually the first element of the array.  Therefore, `*response=*origin;` just copies the value of the first element of the `origin` array to the first element of `response`.  Since you haven't assigned a value to `response[1]`, it contains garbage.

If you want to copy the array data over, you can do a loop:

```
size_t i;
for (i=0; i < 6; ++i)
    response[i] = origin[i];
```

Or, you can use `memcpy()`:

```
memcpy(response, origin, sizeof response);
```

(The above is for C, Objective-C may have differences and other ways of doing what you want to do.)

Comment: thanks for this clear explanation, I just voted it. In java as in some other object oriented language, you may well know that when I write objectx=objecty I got two references to the same object. I was trying to achieve that with objective-c, with a preferred way of learning how to do in a non object oriented language like C.

Comment: @Paul: Thanks!  Time to 'set' myself in the bed now.