# sizeof behaving unexpectedly

Tags: c

Consider the following code:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  int main(void)
  {
    int a[10];
    printf("%d",(int)sizeof(a)); //prints 10*sizeof(int) (40 on my compiler)
    printf("%d",(int)sizeof(a-3)); //prints sizeof(int) (4 on my compiler)

  }
```

I know that `sizeof()` is a compile time operator but I was surprised to see the output of second `printf()`. What could be the reason? Is there an implicit conversion of the argument of `sizeof()` from an array-type to an integer type?

Comment: The second one actually prints `sizeof(int *)`, not `sizeof(int)`. `sizeof(int *)` just happens to be 4 too on your platform.

Comment: Also, the proper way to print a `size_t` value (the value returned by `sizeof`) is with `"%zu"`, assuming your compiler supports that particular C99 feature. If not, a better bet would be to cast it to an `unsigned` or `unsigned long`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `sizeof` operator doesn't evaluate its argument, it only [looks at the type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature/2018786#2018786) of its operand.

Let's say you have an array `a` with type "array [N] of type T". Then, in most cases, the type of the name `a` is "pointer to T" (`T *`), and the value of the pointer is the address of the first element of the array (`&a[0]`).  That is, the name of an array "decays" to a pointer to its first element.  The "decaying" doesn't happen in the following cases:

- when `a` is used with the address-of (`&`) operator,
- in the initialization of `a` (it is illegal to assign to arrays in C), and
- when `a` is the operand of the `sizeof` operator.

So, `sizeof a` gives you `N` times `sizeof(T)`.

When you do `sizeof(a-3)`, the type of the operand to `sizeof` is determined by the expression `a-3`.  Since `a` in `a-3` is used in a [value context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035066/type-of-an-array/2035255#2035255) (i.e., none of the three contexts above), its type is "pointer to int", and the name `a` decays to a pointer to `a[0]`.  As such, calculating `a-3` is undefined behavior, but since `sizeof` doesn't evaluate its argument, `a-3` is used only to determine the type of the operand, so the code is OK (see the first link above for more).

From the above, `sizeof(a-3)` is equivalent to `sizeof(int *)`, which is 4 on your computer.

The "conversion" is due to the subtraction operator.  You can see a similar, and perhaps more surprising, result with the comma operator:

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(1, a));
```

will also print `sizeof(int *)`, because of the comma operator resulting in `a` getting used in a value context.

Answer (score 5):

`(a-3)` has type `int*`, and it prints you `sizeof(int*)` which is 4 on your platform.

And note that `sizeof()` is no longer compile-time constant in C99 (due to variadic-length arrays).

Comment: To be clear - the result of `sizeof` is not a compiler time constant only when the operand is a variable length array.  It still is a constant for other operand types.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, in the second case the argument is interpreted as an `int*` pointer which happens to also have size equal to 4 on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof()` returns the size of a type, so the type is what's important.

It also shouldn't be printed with `%d`.  At the very least, explicitly cast it to `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long` and use the appropriate format specifier.  When teaching C, I had a student get the wrong answer by printing `size_t` with `%d` as the textbook mistakenly said to do.

Anyway, `a` is an array type.  In C, array types decay to pointer types if you do almost anything with them or sneeze loudly, so almost anything you do to `a` will yield a pointer type.  As you've found out, adding or subtracting a number will decay.  (After all, an array can't be used in arithmetic, but a pointer can.)

Comment: @David: as long as the result doesn't overflow, if one casts the expression as `(int)`, then printing it with `"%d"` is okay.  In this case, it is almost certain that the size will fit in an `int`.  In C99, one would use `"%zu"` of course.  For C89, your suggestion is better than printing with `"%d"` after casting as `(int)` because it is more overflow-prone.

Comment: @Alok:  True, but doing the casting is much more important than what you cast to.  Also, I'm very thoroughly familiar with C89, and haven't used C99, and it probably shows.

Comment: The OP has the cast in his question. I agree with you - without the cast, `"%d"` is wrong, but the OP's `printf()` call is OK as long as there is no overflow.