# Unable to assign structure variable to another structure variable

Tags: c, struct, variable-assignment

I am unable to assign one structure variable (`R2 = R1`) to another structure variable. Please help me to understand, why the following program is not getting compiled and what is the best way to assign one structure variable to other?

I'm tired with the pointers way. Still code is not getting compiled...

**Code1**:

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct Record
{
    int ID;
    char Name[];
} R1 = {1234, "King"}, R2;

R2 = R1;

int main()
{
    printf("%d   %s \n", R1.ID, R1.Name);
    printf("%d   %s \n", R2.ID, R2.Name);
}
```

**Code2:**

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct Record
{
    int ID;
    char Name[];
} R1 = {1234, "King"}, *R2;

R2 = &R1;

int main()
{

    printf("%d   %s \n", R1.ID, R1.Name);
    printf("%d   %s \n", R2->ID, R2->Name);
}
```

Comment: And please, **declare** and **set** the two struct variables **in** the `main()` function. It hurts the eyes..

Comment: I tried below,
#include<stdio.h>

struct Record
{
 int ID;
 char Name[10];
}R1={1234,"King"},*R2;

R2=&R1;

int main()
{
    
 printf("%d   %s \n",R1.ID,R1.Name);
 printf("%d   %s \n",R2->ID,R2->Name);
}

Still not working

Comment: See my updated question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct _Record
{
    int ID;
    char Name[10];
} Record;

int main()
{
    Record R1, R2;
    R1.ID = 1234;
    strcpy(R1.Name, "king");
    R2 = R1;
    printf("%d   %s \n",R1.ID,R1.Name);
    printf("%d   %s \n",R2.ID,R2.Name);
}

>>>
1234 king
1234 king
```

As @piedar said, the following also works

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct _Record
{
    int ID;
    char *Name;
} R1={1234,"king"}, R2;

int main()
{
    R2 = R1;
    printf("%d   %s \n",R1.ID,R1.Name);
    printf("%d   %s \n",R2.ID,R2.Name);
}
```

Comment: Hi Zian, thanks..But why my Code 1 and Code 2 are not working? Could you please explain?

Comment: Did you try your edited code? No, it will *not* work, you cannot assign to a `char[]`. Printing that will show you that `R2.name` is an empty string.

Comment: Hi @user1031438 your code isn't working  because u're not declaring the variable properly and inside a scope with the variable type. You're trying to use R1 & R2 as if they were already declared somewhere in program as global variable.

Comment: @bnaecker I fixed it. btw, can you explain why using `char Name[]` would not work here.

Comment: @ZianLai That is an array. You cannot assign to an array, as far as I'm aware. You must use `char *name`, which can be pointed anywhere, including at an existing `char[]` array.

Comment: It seems copying is automatic if the size is known; probably the compiler emits memcpy() or equivalent.  The `char*` is just an offset into rodata and can be copied (safely?) since it has static storage.

Comment: @ZianLai, The code is running after putting R2=R1; in main(). But as per C standards, is there any rule that, we can't assign structure variables outside any function? What is the concept working here?

Comment: @user1031438 according to my experiences, you can't run code outside of function. You can only declare variables outside of functions. Hope it helps.

Comment: @bnaecker that's not true. Arrays wrapped inside structs will be copied as normal. That's one trick when you want to pass arrays as values to functions. See [Deep copying structs with char arrays in C (How to copy the arrays?)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29989516/995714). The problem here is just about the empty `[]` when declaring the array

Answer (score 0):

In `Code1`, you can't use `R2=R1` outside C functions, otherwise GCC will report errors. Just move `R2=R1;` into the `main` function and then your program will work normally.

Similarly, move `R2=&R1;` into the `main` function.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't reserved any space for the string. An array with **no size** at the end of a struct is called [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)

```
struct Record
{
    int ID;
    char Name[];
}
```

You have to allocate some memory for the string [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3047530/995714)

```
struct Record R1 = malloc(sizeof(struct Record) + 10 * sizeof(char));
```

Alternatively declare `Name` as a `char*` then allocate memory and copy the string like normal. Remember to delete the pointer when you finished using it

Or just avoid flexible array member and declare a fixed size for `Name`