# Array assignment inside a Struct

Tags: c

I understand that normally arrays are unassignable. However I recently came across this

```
struct S {
    int arr[6];
};
```

And this lets me do something like this

```
struct S a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
struct S b;
b = a; // b.arr is now a deep clone of a.arr?
```

This seems odd because I would have thought such assignment would result in a shallow copy being stored in b, as only the address of the first element of a.arr would be copied?

Comment: I think you are doing the `arrays == pointers` thing.  This is not true.  `arr` is, in fact, an array.  This is actually copying the data.  In fact, if the array is big enough, the compiler could emit a `memcpy` call.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deep copying structs with char arrays in C (How to copy the arrays?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29989516/deep-copying-structs-with-char-arrays-in-c-how-to-copy-the-arrays)

Comment: How could it do a shallow copy? There's no pointer in the struct.

Comment: ... and if it contained pointers, it would be a shallow copy since it would only copy the pointers and not what they point at. See it as `memcpy(&b, &a, sizeof(S));`

Comment: Arrays are not assignable because it is not possible to form a value of array type, this expression will automatically decay to a pointer. So assignments for arrays are disallowed because there is nothing that could be assigned to an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays are strange in C. They're distinct from pointers, but many operations on them make them implicitly *decay* into pointers, which can misguide you to think they the same.

This array is stored inline into each `struct S` instance. Upon assignment, its copied in its entirety, just like any other `int` members that might be inside the struct instance. There's no shallow-copy vs deep-copy distinction here, because there is no out-of-line pointer-referenced data to be worried about.

Answer (score 2):

It is not an array only a struct. Structs (and unions) in C can be assigned and passed to the function and returned from the function.

```
struct S a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
struct S b;
b = a;
```

> // b.arr is now a deep clone of a.arr?

Yes it is. The whole structure (in this case it has only one member)  is being copied.