# Trouble with dangling pointers and character arrays in C

Tags: c, pointers, dangling-pointer

```
main(){
   char *cmd1[20] = {NULL};
   int x = parse_command(cmd1);
   printf("%s\ ",cmd1[0]);
}

parse_command(char *inTempString){
   char tempString[256];
   (call to function that assigns a string to tempString)
   cmd1[0] = tempString;
}
```

There is a problem when printing out the `cmd1[0]` within `main`. I am pretty sure that it is a dangling pointer error. I don't really know how to go about fixing it.

Comment: Yeah -- I'm not clear on where `cmd1` in `parse_command` is coming from.  This code looks fairly buggy in things like that, which is no doubt obscuring the real error.

Answer (score 4):

There are two issues with your program.

First, when you say:

```
char *cmd1[20] = {NULL};
```

`cmd1` is an array of 20 pointers to `char`.  This means that `cmd1[i]` for `i` in [0,20) is a pointer to `char`.

There is a rule in C that says that passing an array to a function only passes the pointer to the first element of the array to the function.  I.e., if you had code like:

```
int ai[20];
f(ai);
```

then the type of `ai` in the function call `f(ai);` is `int *` and the pointer passed to `f()` is equal to `&ai[0]`, the first element of `ai`.

So, when you do:

```
parse_command(cmd1);
```

you immediately know that the "thing" passed to `parse_command()` is `&cmd1[0]`, i.e., a pointer to the first element of `cmd1`.  Since `cmd1[0]` is of type `char *`, you are passing a `char **` to `parse_command`.  Therefore, your declaration:

```
parse_command(char *inTempString);
```

is wrong, you should do:

```
parse_command(char **inTempString);
```

to match your call.  This assumes that `parse_command()` will parse more than one value in `cmd1`.  If that is the case, you should also pass the number of elements in `cmd1` to `parse_commnd()`—since it can't know how many elements `cmd1` has.

Your second problem is that you can't return the address of a local variable from a function in C.  As above, in addition to a function call, returning an array in C, or assigning something to an array in C also makes the name of an array "decay" to a pointer to its first element.

So given your function:

```
/* changed inTempString to cmd1 because that's what you probably meant */
int parse_command(char *cmd1)
{
    char tempString[256];
    /* call to function that assigns a string to tempString */
    cmd1[0] = tempString;
    /* you need to return an int from here */
}
```

the `tempString` in the assignment to `cmd1[0]` is actually `&tempString[0]`, i.e., a pointer to the first element of `tempString`.  But since `tempString` is destroyed as soon as the function returns, the pointer becomes invalid.  You can't use the value later.

In fact, in C, the name of an array decays to a pointer to its first element in all cases, except:

- when used as an operand to `sizeof` operator, and
- when used as an operand to the address-of (`&`) operator

To be more precise, in object contexts, the name of an array doesn't decay to a pointer, and in value contexts, it decays to a pointer.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035066/type-of-an-array/2035255#2035255) for more details.

Now, how should you fix your second issue?  It depends—you can either allocate memory dynamically in `parse_command()`, and assign that memory to `cmd1[0]`, or you can make `tempString` `static` in the function.  Since `static` variables in a function are not destroyed when a function returns, you can continue using a pointer to it.  Dynamic allocation is more work—you need to worry about allocation failure and you need to remember to free the pointer when done.  `static` array is easier, but you have to be careful because another call to `parse_command` will overwrite the array, making it less-generic.

Assuming you want to go the "dynamic memory" route, here is a scheme that you could use:

```
#include <stdio.h> /* printf */
#include <stdlib.h> /* malloc and free */

int main(void) /* main returns int */
{
    char *cmd1[20] = {NULL};
    /* number of commands.  "sizeof cmd1" is the number of bytes
       used by the cmd1 array, and "sizeof cmd1[0]" is the number
       of bytes used by one element of the array.  The division
       gives you the number of elements.  This is 20 of course
       but doing it this way makes sure that changing "20" to any
       number works. */
    size_t ncmds = sizeof cmd1 / sizeof cmd1[0];
    /* pass the number of commands to "parse_command", since
       it can't know otherwise */
    int x = parse_command(cmd1, ncmds);
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < x; ++i) {
        printf("%s ", cmd1[i]);
        free(cmd1[i]);
    }
    return 0; /* return a value from main */
}

int parse_command(char **cmd1, size_t ncmds)
{
    char *tempString; /* we will malloc this */
    int i; /* the number of mallocs done successfully */
    tempString = malloc(...);
    if (tempString == NULL) {
    /* failure, handle gracefully */
    } else {
        ++i; /* make sure i doesn't exceed or equal ncmds */
    }
    cmd1[0] = tempString;
    /* do the above as many times as you need */
    return i; /* the number successfully assigned to */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring cmd1 in main as a char** -- that is, a pointer to pointer to char.  However, you then pass it to parse_command, which you've defined as taking a char*; a pointer to char.

This only compiles because of automatic conversion of pointer-to-anything to pointer-to-char.  That's a historical artifact of old versions of C that used 'char*' in place of 'void*'; in your case, it just means that the compiler is ignoring the type error that you made rather than reporting it to you.

Comment: `cmd1` is not declared `char **`.  It's an array of pointers.  When passed to a function, it decays to a pointer to the first element of the array, which is `char **`.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can't do that.

```
char tempString[256];
```

declares a variable on the stack in the function `parse_command`, that variable goes out of scope and pointers to it cease to be valid when `parse_command` returns.

You need to allocate the command string on the heap, so that it will still be valid when `parse_command` returns. This is one way.

```
parse_command(char *inTempString){
   char tempString[256];
   (call to function that assigns a string to tempString)

   int cb = strlen(tempString)+1;
   cmd1[0] = (char *)malloc(cb);
   strcpy(cmd1[0], tempString);
}
```

You should also call `free(cmd[0])` before main exits.

In addition to that, this code doesn't compile.  You can't reference `cmd1[0]` from inside the `parse_command` function.  You should be getting a type mismatch when you try and pass `cmd1` into `parse_command`,  If you mean to return a char* from `parse_command` then it should be declared to take a char** as an argument, more like this.

```
parse_command(char **pcmd){
   char tempString[256];
   (call to function that assigns a string to tempString)

   int cb = strlen(tempString)+1;
   pcmd[0] = (char *)malloc(cb);
   strcpy(pcmd[0], tempString);
}
```

Comment: @Brooks: yes, on the assumption that most of the 256 bytes isn't needed most of the time, we go ahead and read into the stack and then decide how much to allocate.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work:

```
parse_command(char **inTempString){
        static char tempString[256];
        strcpy(tempString,"some string you want to copy");
        inTempString[0] = tempString;
}
```

- In your code the tempString would not
  exist once the function returns. You
  need to keep it alive even after the
  function returns. You can allocate
  the space dynamically and de-allocate
  later or you can declare it as
  static.
- Also you need to change the type
  argument inTempString from char* to
  char**.

Comment: This works, but it only works _once_.  I'm not sure this is a good recommendation to someone who is struggling with pointers.

Answer (score 0):

**You are trying to access `cmd1` variable that is inside `main` function from `parse_command`.**

I would say that at least the `cmd1[0]` will look like an integer because it is not declared withing that method.

The `cmd1` is declared as `array of char*` but the parameter to method is `char*` which might be a `pointer to char array` but **not** `pointer to array of char*`.

The best way to copy char array into another char array is to use either `memcpy`,`strcpy` or similar methods that accept pointers to src, dest and size to be copied.