# how to initialize an array?

Tags: c

I have a 3dimensional array, how do I initialize it to a default value without having 3 loops.

```
dummy[4][4][1024]
```

, how do I initialize all the elements to 12?

Comment: What's wrong with 3 loops? It is the clearest way to initialize the array. Have pity on the reader.

Comment: I agree, I was wondering if I can do all in oneshot, some compilers and in some other platforms we can directly initialize, was checking how does that work in C

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fastest way to zero out a 2d array in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516096/fastest-way-to-zero-out-a-2d-array-in-c)

Answer (score 10):

Since the 3-d array is a contiguous block of memory, you can view it as a 1-d array

```
int i, *dummy2 = &dummy[0][0][0];
for(i = 0; i < 4*4*1024; ++i)
    dummy2[i] = 12;
```

Comment: That's undefined behaviour.

Comment: @DanielFischer you need to declare `int i` too :)

Comment: BTW what's wrong with `int *dummy2 = (int *)dummy` instead of `&dummy[0][0][0]`?

Comment: Nothing. I just thought of taking the address first, @EitanT.

Comment: @EitanT: explicit casts may hide bugs. This version will fail to compile when the base type of the array changes to, say, `long long`. The version with the explicit cast still compiles but produces the wrong behavior.

Comment: it is not an initialization but assignment

Comment: Can't deny that, @Jens, to _initialize_ `dummy` so that each element is set to 12, there is no portable way except having 16384 `12`s in the source code, or is there?

Comment: sure, there is no other way, but that's what the OP asked for. It seems s/he istn't even aware of the initializer syntax in C.

Comment: @Jens I rather think it's the use of the term 'initialization' in the sense of setting values before use, not in the technical sense of the standard.

Comment: @DanielFischer, only he or she can tell

Answer (score 7):

Come on guys - let's do it the simple way that always works:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
  for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
  {
    for(int k = 0; k < 1024; k++)
    {
      dummy[i][j][k] = 12;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I also like this one better. Especially since compilers may well optimize this code and make it as good as the most voted answer.

Comment: @betabandido Even if not, the difference would be marginal. The only reason for treating it as a 1-d array was that the OP asked to do it "without having 3 loops".

Comment: @DanielFischer that's a good one... my eyes skipped that part :)

Answer (score 5):

The default initialization to all zeros is just that:

```
unsigned dummy[4][4][1024] = { 0 };
```

If you want to initialize particular elements (and all others to zero) do this

```
unsigned dummy[4][4][1024] = { { { 5 }, { 0, 4 } } };
```

and if your compiler knows C99 use designated initializers

```
unsigned dummy[4][4][1024] = { [3] = { [2] = { [0] = 7 }, [1] = { [2] = 3, [1] = 4 } } };
```

and if you really insist to use all `12`, just repeat the `12` 16384 times :)