# Access violation writing error on writing to a 2D array after initializing using memset

Tags: c++, memset

I am using Visual Studio Community 2017.

Following the discussion below:

[Fastest way to zero out a 2d array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516096/fastest-way-to-zero-out-a-2d-array-in-c)

I have a 2 D matrix (10 x 10) that I initialize using `memset`. This is option 1.

Option 2 is initializing the same matrix using two `for` loops, each looping from 0 through 9.

Then, when I write to a valid matrix location, an access violation writing error is thrown when Option 1 was used. Everything works fine when Option 2 is used.

The minimal working code I have that replicates this is given below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <array> 



int main(){
    double ** cmatrix = new double*[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cmatrix[i] = new double[10];

    memset(cmatrix, 0, 10 * 10 * sizeof(double));//Option 1    

    //for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)//Option 2
        //for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            //cmatrix[i][j] = 0;

    cmatrix[0][1] = 5;//This step produces error on Option 1, but not on option 2

    return 0;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `memset` requires that the memory to fill is one contiguous area, but you have 11 separate allocations.

Comment: Don't use answers to C questions in C++. They are different languages; the use of `memset` for this is neither necessary nor a good idea.

Comment: [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays)

Comment: Btw if you just wished to set everything to zero you should have used `calloc`. That being said, using `malloc`/`calloc` in C++ is _always_ incorrect practice, no exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `memset` you're overriding the pointers returned by your memory allocations, therefore when you access the memory later you're actually deferring a null pointer.

Your 2D array is actually an array of pointers, so memory is not contiguous and you cannot do a `memset` to set it to 0. Technically, it is just a pointer and dynamically you allocate space for another 10 pointers, each of them pointing to 10 doubles.

Instead, use a double loop (nested-fors) to initialize it, or just one `memset` for each row:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
    cmatrix[i][j] = 0.0;

// or

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  memset(cmatrix[i], 0, 10 * sizeof(double));
```

Also, if your array will always be 10x10 you can declare it instead as `double cmatrix[10][10]`: that memory is contiguous and you can do your original `memset`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I was able to verify that it works with a 1 D array's memset. So, for a 2d array, I will use your suggestioin.

Comment: "Your 2D array is actually an array of arrays, so memory is not contiguous" This is incorrect. It is actually an array of _pointers_. Had it been an array of arrays, memory _would_ have been contiguous.

Comment: @Lundin thanks for the correction, I'll fix the answer to be more specific

Comment: If you have a contiguous array you can do `double cmatrix[10][10] = {};` and the compiler will clear it for you. No need for `memset`.

Answer (score 2):

`cmatrix` is a array of pointers.
A call of `memset` to zero on it, will in fact be setting all pointers to 0 (which is not what you want), which leads to the access violation later.
For this kind of initialization I would choose the option 2 (the one in comments)

Comment: From your post, I understand that one cannot use memset on 2d arrays. Is that right? I am confused because https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516096/fastest-way-to-zero-out-a-2d-array-in-c seems to suggest that as a valid way to initialize 2d arrays.

Comment: @Tryer. It works for 2d arrays, but not for those which are dynamically allocated.Try the same with `double cmatrix[10][10]`

Comment: @Tryer actually the OP of that question mentioned a 2D array, not an array of pointers (although didn't showed the code), probably your confusion came from there

Comment: @Tryer It's not exactly true. In fact in the post you mentionned I supposed their 2d array was declared on the stack (for ex : double array[10][10], in which case   the memory is contiguous and the memset will work fine). In your case you are declaring a array of pointers. So memory zone on which the pointers are stored is contiguous but not the pointed data.

Answer (score 2):

In this code:

> ```
> double ** cmatrix = new double*[10];
> for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
>     cmatrix[i] = new double[10];
> ```

you first allocate an array of 10 *pointers* to `double` (`double*`), and then, *for each* element (pointer) in this array, you allocate a *new* array of 10 `double`s.

Graphically:

```
 array of 
 double*
   ||
   \/
+------+
|  x----------->   [0|1|... <10 doubles> ...|9]
+------+
|  x----------->   [0|1|... <10 doubles> ...|9]
+------+
| ...  |
+------+
|  x----------->   [0|1|... <10 doubles> ...|9]
+------+
```

You can't call `memset` to zero out this data structure, as you allocated *scattered* memory, instead a single call to `memset` requires *contiguous* memory.

You can do a simple `memset` invocation if you *linearize* the 2D array, i.e. allocating a single chunk of memory storing 10*10 = 100 `double`s, with a single call to `new[]`.

Comment: Thanks for the graphical depiction. So, [1][0] does not follow [0][9] while dynamically allocated as I had. Had cmatrix been declared as cmatrix[10][10], it would have been fine. Is that right?

Comment: @Tryer: Yes, with `double cmatrix[10][10]` you get a contiguous memory block.