# How is printf statement interpreted?

Tags: c, programming-languages, printf

How is the following line interpreted by GCC compiler:

```
printf("HELLO");
```

I want to know this because when I am running following program:

```
main()  
{  
    printf(5+"Good Morning");  
}
```

The program is printing:

```
Morning
```

Why is the compiler is starting the printing from the sixth character?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are a lot of things happening here.  As others have said, `printf()` doesn't 'know' anything about the expression `5+"Good Morning"`.  The value of that expression is determined by the C language.

First, `a+b` is the same as `b+a`, so `5+"Good Morning"` is the same as `"Good Morning"+5`.

Now, the type of `"Good Morning"` (i.e., a string literal) is an "array of `char`".  Specifically, `"Good Morning"` is a 13-character array (12 "regular" characters, followed by a `0`).  When used in most expressions, the [type of an array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035066/type-of-an-array/2035255#2035255) "decays" to a pointer to its first element, and binary addition is one such case.  All this means that in `"Good Morning"+5`, `"Good Morning"` decays to a pointer to its first element, which is the character `G`.

Here is how the memory looks like:

```
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0   1   2
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| G | o | o | d |   | M | o | r | n | i | n | g | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

The value of the address of `G` plus 5 is a pointer that points to 5 locations from `G` above, which is `M`.  So, `printf()` is getting an address that is at `M`.  `printf()` prints that till it finds a `0`.  Hence you see `Morning` as output.

Comment: +1 for not dumbing it down (esp. "in most expressions, the type of an array in C "decays" to a pointer to its first element" instead of "la la la, an array is a pointer, la la la")

Answer (score 25):

This is an artifact of C pointer-arithmetic; `printf` is just a red herring.

The type of a string literal (such as `"Good morning`") is `const char *`.  Your code is equivalent to:

```
const char *p = "Good morning";
p = p + 5;
printf(p);
```

Adding a pointer and an integer produces a pointer to the 5th element in the sequence.

Answer (score 7):

Is is the same as writing

```
char *ptr="Good Morning";
```

followed by

```
printf( ptr + 5 );
```

which is `&ptr[5]` this adress points to "Morning";

Adding an integer n to a pointer results to an adress ptr + n * sizeof(type)

Answer (score 4):

Because `"Good Morning"` is a pointer to the string (actually to the first byte of it) and adding 5 to that pointer yields a pointer to the 5th character. C strings are null-terminated, so either way, `printf` runs until it encounters the null at the end.

Answer (score 3):

It advances the input pointer by 5 bytes and hence skips the word "Good".

This is [pointer arithmetic](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10b.html) in C.

Lets assume base pointer of the string "Good Morning" is p, and 5+p =p+5 and it points to letter M.

Hence the input to printf is the pointer from the letter M.