# What exactly does &(p[*(i + j)]) do?

Tags: c

Running the following code will print out `orld`. What is happening here? What exactly does `&(p[*(i + j)])` do?

```
#include <stdio.h>
char p[] = "HelloWorld";
int i[] = {2,1,3,5,6}, j = 4;

int main()
{
    printf(&(p[*(i + j)]));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: _pointer arithmetic_

Comment: p is `char[]` and ur passing &p to printf. The start is given by expression `*(i+j) == 6` It will print the entire char array until it hits the escape character `\0`. If you want to print only the character at the location try `p[*(i+j)]`

Comment: Is this an execise? I hope nobody writes such things in real life.

Comment: Start from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-c-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a , which explains the inner-most part.

Comment: @Jens: It is an exercice I stumbled on.

Comment: So then asking that question here is completely counter productive. Search the web / documentation / whatever to understand enough to solve it yourself.

Comment: To the people voting for close: Could you please explain what is unclear? He has a perfectly clear question that can be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to simplify it step by step

```
#include <stdio.h>
char p[] = "HelloWorld";
int i[] = {2,1,3,5,6}, j = 4;

int main()
{
    printf(&(p[*(i + j)]));
    return 0;
}
```

The first three lines are obvious:

- `p` is an array of 10 characters
- `i` is an array of 5 integers
- `j` is an integer and has the value 4

`printf(&(p[*(i + j)]));`

is the same as

`printf(&(p[*(i + 4)]));`

is the same as

`printf(&(p[*([adress of first element of i] + 4)]));`

is the same as

`printf(&(p[*([adress of fourth element of i])]));`

Now you have to know what `*address` gives you the value that is in `address`. So:

`printf(&(p[6]));`

Now that's the point where I guess you were struggling. You have to know:

- arrays are basically nothing else
  than a part in memory that is continuous. It is specified by it's starting address.
- `&something` gives you the address of `something`

So this "slices" the array `HelloWorld` to `orld`. In Python you would write `p[6:]`, in C you write `&p[6]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
char p[] = "HelloWorld";
int i[] = {2,1,3,5,6}, j = 4;
```

`&(p[*(i + j)])` is evaluated as below:

here `i` is the `base address` of `array i`. Thus `i+4` will be the `address` of the `fifth element` in the `array i`. `*(i+j)` will be equal to `6`. `P[6]` will be `o` after `W`. `&(p[*(i + j)])` would be **equal** to `&p[6]`. Thus in `printf` you are passing the `address of o` and the **output** would be `orld`.

Comment: So printf(&p[6]) will print the content of array p until it hits \0? How is this mechanism called?

Comment: @mcwise yes it is. printf takes the address of string to be printed and it prints the string until it hits \0

Comment: @mcwise: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332611/how-is-printf-statement-interpreted/ .

Answer (score 3):

Let's start off by learning these couple of facts:

**1)** *Arrays* are sequence of allocated memory locations. The array label itself, is the address of the memory location of the very first element of the sequence. Example:

```
int asd[5] = { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };    // <-- this is an array

/* the following is what it looks like in the memory:
11  12  13  14  15

the value of, for example, asd[4] is 15
the value of asd itself is the memory address of asd[0], the very first element
so the following is true:
asd == &asd[0]  */
```

**2)** When the programme encounters a string literal, that is, anything inside double quotes, like `"HelloWorld"` in your example, it fills some memory location with those characters, and then one more character, `'\0'` as a mark of end, so that programme may know when to stop; then, it returns the memory location of the first character. So in other words, `"HelloWorld"` alone creates an array and returns the label of that array.

**3)** `asd[3]`, `*(asd + 3)` and `3[asd]`, all are the same; they all point to the content of the memory location that has the address `asd + 3`. The pointer type of the `asd` is important here, it determines how much bits/bytes to offset from the `asd`. As for `int * asd`, `asd + 3` will advance `3 * sizeof ( int )` bytes ahead of the `asd`.

Now, with all this, let's examine what `&( p[ *(i + j) ] )` really is:

```
    &( p[ *( i + j ) ] )
    &( p[ *( i + 4 ) ] )
    &( p[    i[4]    ] )
    &( p[      6     ] )    // This will return the address of `7th` element to the printf. 
     ( p      +      6 )    // A pointer to second 'o'
```

Then this is pushed into the `printf` as the `const char *` argument, which prints `'o'`, then `'r'`, then `'l'`, then `'d'`, and then encounters the `'\0'`, thus understands that the string is over and stops there.

Comment: Good explanation. +1. But you should remove the line `&( "HelloWorld"[6] )` and `"HelloWorld"  +  6`. It is bit confusing to a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go by steps: `*(i+j)` it's the same as `i[j]`, that is `6`. `p[6]` is the value at p pointer plus 6.

The address of operator get the address of that character, thus a `char*`.

A char pointer pointing to the 6th character of `p` passed to the printf function print the text "orld".

Answer (score 1):

`&(p[*(i + j)])` leads to below expression which is address of `p[6]` being `j = 4`.

`&(p[*(i + j)]) == &(p[(i[j])]) ==  &(p[(i[4])]) == &(p[6]) == &p[6]`

Yes you can print using `printf` without format `%s` specifier since it takes strings as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Read comments for explanation

```
#include <stdio.h>
char p[] = "HelloWorld";
int i[] = {2,1,3,5,6}, j = 4;

int main()
{
    printf(&(p[*(i + j)])); //*(i+j) = i[j] => i[4]= 6
    // &(p[*(i + j)]) => place the pointer in memory block that his address p[6]
    // so printf print the string starting from the p[6] ie from 'o' => orld
    return 0;
}
```