# Why does this happen in C? Incompatible assignment for pointers

Tags: c, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is array name a pointer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c)
>   [Array Type - Rules for assignment/use as function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035066/array-type-rules-for-assignment-use-as-function-parameter)

This is the code that i wrote for an exercise in K&R C. The task is pretty simple, to replace '\t' with \ and t and not the tab character

the following is the code

```
char* escape(char s[], char t[]){
 int i = 0, j = 0;
 for(i = 0; t[i] != '\0'; i++){
   switch(t[i]){
     case '\t':{
        s[j++] = '\\';
        s[j++] = 't';
        break;
     }
     default:{
        s[j++] = t[i];
        break;
     }
   }
  }
 s[j] = t[i];
 return s;

 }


 int main(){        
    char t[10] = "what \t is";
    char s[50];
    s = escape(s,t);
    printf("%s",s);
    return 0;
 }
```

It returns an error saying inappropriate type assignment betweenn char[50] and char* but isn't the name of the array supposed to be the pointer to the first element?

Comment: You can't assign to an array, you can `strcpy` to it though.

Comment: Voting to close. please read the C FAQ first: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/arrayassign.html

Comment: I believe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335786/c-differences-between-pointer-and-array discussion will fully answer your question. It describes difference between array and pointer to an array pretty well.

Comment: When posting an error, always post the *exact* error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C arrays aren't writable lvalues. You can't assign to them. **In your code you don't actually need to return anything** from the function since it changes `s` in place. But if you really want to:

```
char *s = malloc(...);
s = escape(s, t);
```

This means you will later have to free it etc. In short, don't return anything from the function and it's going to be ok.

> but isn't the name of the array supposed to be the pointer to the
>   first element

That's an over-simplification. Thing is arrays typically decay into pointers to the first element **in certain contexts**.

Comment: Yeah I worked around by not returning anything.

Comment: @sukun007 It's good to make your code work. But always make sure you understand the implications.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an array to a pointer but not viceversa.

Answer (score 0):

It works the other way around: you can pass an array where a pointer is expected. But that doesnt mean you can assign a pointer to an array name. Think about it, when you say

```
char s[50];
```

the compiler just reserves space for 50 characters and remembers that s is a pointer to those 50 characters. It is, so to speak, a constant. You can change the characters in the array, but not where the array is.